# Can I make 'if' check 'array' in AS3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

My goal is this. I have:

```
var cantDelete:Array = ['btn_backFolder', 'btn_nextPage'];
//I have one Array with names of MovieClips
```

I want to see if e.target.name is not equal to array.

To avoid writing of:

```
if (e.target.name == 'btn_backFolder' && e.target.name == 'btn_nextPage')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to see if e.target.name is not equal to array.

Object isn't found in the given array:

```
if(cantDelete.indexOf(e.target.name) == -1){
    trace("Isn't found in the array");
}
```